# Profile picture from Facebook Graph not rendering in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to a very simple task and display a user's Facebook profile picture on my Rails app. Doing the following in a test HTML file works just fine:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <img src="http://graph.facebook.com/4/picture?type=square" />
  </body>
</html>
```

The image source is following the redirect and gets rendered. However for some reason in my Rails app, I'm using the following:

```
image_tag "http://graph.facebook.com/4/picture?type=square"
```

And it's not being rendered. In Chrome dev tools I'm seeing that the file is zero bytes and the image is 1x1px.

[image: Chrome Dev Tools]

I'm using Ruby 2.0.0, Rails 4.0.2 and HAML.

**UPDATE:**
I've got the same project running on another machine in a Vagrant VM (Ubuntu) and the image is rendering fine.

Comment: http://graph.facebook.com/4/picture?type=normal      try this to run in your browser. if the photo gets.. then its way better

Comment: But the dev tool is showing *graph.facebook.com/4*, not *graph.facebook.com/4/picture?type=square*?

Comment: @cjnahine05 adding the `normal` parameter doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: @SahilMittal the second line in dev tools just shows the URL without the resource, so the full URL is `graph.facebook.com/4/picture`

Comment: @cjnahine05 I'm not sure how that's different to what I've already got?

Comment: Strange !! I tried the same code and it rendered correctly.

Comment: Can you paste the produced html for the image tag?

Comment: @jackbot, can you come back to this? Can you paste the produced html for the image tag?

Comment: The HTML is standard, it produces `<img alt="Profile" src="http://graph.facebook.com/4/picture">`

Comment: which rails version your using, be specific.

Answer (score 0):

You could try out with : **https**, i.e.:

> `https://graph.facebook.com/<id>/picture?type=square`

Since this url ultimately redirects to https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/, and auto redirection works automatically when original and redirected protocols are **same**. So probably using `https` with the url may work!

---

If still didn't works, make the API call to-

> `http://graph.facebook.com/<id>/picture?redirect=false`

and you'll get the response as-

```
{
  data: {
    url: "https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-.....jpg",
    is_silhouette: false
  }
}
```

Just use this `url`.

Comment: Hmm no luck, HTTPS seems to do the same.

Comment: Strange! If added another solution, pl check

Comment: Thanks but I really want to just use the image src rather than having to make 2 requests for each picture.